# Spring cloud data stream deploy stuck on load

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am a beginner to spring cloud data flow and i am following their official doc. But when i deploy the stream from spring cloud data flow dashboard it just stuck on loading and the stream is never deployed.

The DSL for the stream i want to deploy is:
    `http | log`

I changed the ports for skipper but nothing works

I expect that when i click on deploy the stream then it should show me the status 'deploying' but instead it just keeps on loading forever.

Answer (score 0):

When reporting for issues like this, it'd be great if you could share the versions in use and the logs for review.

Depending on the platform (local, cf or k8s), I'd recommend reviewing the [troubleshooting steps](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/troubleshooting/debugging-scdf-streams/) included in the SCDF Microsite.

If you followed those steps and if you still see issues, please update the description of the post with the relevant details, and we can review then.